# ggsurvplot+facet_grid graph_not starting form 100%(or 1) at the x=0

Tags: r, survival

I am doing survival analysis using survival and survminer package.
When I draw a single variable survival graph, I can see it starts form 1 at the baseline.
However, when I am tring to draw facet_grid graph,
I find that the survival graph from same data dose not start form 100%(or 1) at the x=0.(Please see the 5th image from the picture below.)
Any ideas why that happens?

To sum-up, the survival rate by time-point are like this.
[image]

However, the survival graph shows like this.
[image]

Comment: @YacineHajji There wasn't an event at the baseline. The survival rate was 1 but the graph is shown like that.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput` and code instead of images please?